# Ruby: How to parse json to specific types

Tags: json, ruby, typesafe

I have a JSON that I want to parse in Ruby. Ruby is completely new to me, but I have to work with it :-)

Here is my litte snippet, that should do the parsing:

```
response = File.read("app/helpers/example_announcement.json")
JSON.parse(response)
```

this works pretty fine. The only downside is, I do not know the properties at the point where I use it, it is not typesafe. So I created the objects for it

```
class Announcements
    @@announcements = Hash # a map key => value where key is string and value is type of  Announcement
end

class Announcement
    @@name = ""
    @@status = ""
    @@rewards = Array
end
```

And this is how the json looks like

```
{
  "announcements": {
    "id1" : {
      "name": "The Diamond Announcement",
      "status": "published",
      "reward": [
        {
          "id": "hardCurrency",
          "amount": 100
        }
      ]
    },
    "id2":   {
      "name": "The Normal Announcement",
      "players": [],
      "status": "published",
      "reward": []
    }
  }
}
```

So I tried JSON parsing like this

```
response = File.read("app/helpers/example_announcement.json")
JSON.parse(response, Announcements)
```

But this is not how it works^^can anybody help me with this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What end result are you looking for? What do you mean by "I do not know the properties at the point where I use it"? (If the JSON is totally arbitrary, then there's not much you can do safely besides display it!! Does it not conform to some schema?)

Comment: If you simply want to create some "arbitrary" structure out of the JSON, then forget creating your own classes (since you "don't know what format the JSON is"???); the best you can do is: `JSON.parse(response, object_class: OpenStruct)`. But again I ask, why do you want to do this? What are you hoping to achieve?

Comment: Additionally ruby does not really work on type safety. Ruby believes heavily in duck typing which allows for inherent flexibility. If you know what an `Announcement` is then it would probably make more sense to have it wrap the parsing rather than parse and pass into it. Also class variables `@@` are not generally recommended by most rubyists. Please explain your concept a bit more as to the whys and the hows and your anticipated usage

Comment: Ok, we have a backend running Scala that defines how the structure looks like. The frontend is written in Ruby. It reads the data from api endpoints. Since our frontend developers do not know about the data structure, we want to implement a generator that creates ruby classes from our Scala data types to make it easier for the frontend developers to understand what data they'll receive, But if this is not the concept in Ruby, then we'll go others way with API documentation. As I said, I am not from the ruby world, but from Scala, but we inherited the Ruby frontend^^